# When does a .com domain become available after it expires? (With status clientTransferProhibited)

Tags: domains, name, icann, expiry

the domain I want is taken and according to ICANN it expires on 2021-01-05. The only status it has is "clientTransferProhibited". I am not sure how to interpret this domain status... Does this status prohibit me from getting the domain once it has expired? And can I acquire the domain as soon as it expires according to the expiry date on ICANN?

Comment: clientTransferProhibited has no bearing on the issue, so this is the same question that has already been asked.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this status prohibit me from getting the domain once it has expired?

No.

> And can I acquire the domain as soon as it expires according to the expiry date on ICANN?

No. (And you have to be careful how you read things depending on where you look, to clearly understand the difference between registry expiration date and registrar expiration date; if you are not sure, this other answer from me can help too: https://serverfault.com/a/885149/396475).

It depends on the registrar, which you don't state. And it has nothing to do with status `clientTransferProhibited`.

TL;DR: it can be between 30+5 (35) days after expiration up to almost 45+30+5 (80) days after expiration, and add even some extra days in the worst case. Those are typical numbers for most gTLDs, but some may use other periods (the period length itself is not an ICANN requirement; having the period itself is a requirement, so once a domain is expired it goes into `autoRenewPeriod` then if it is deleted it goes to `redemptionPeriod` then `pendingDelete`).

See [image: gTLD lifecycle] for a generic introduction.

Also see https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
for an explanation of this status:

> This status indicates that it is not possible to transfer the domain name registration, which will help prevent unauthorized transfers resulting from hijacking and/or fraud. If you do want to transfer your domain, you must first contact your registrar and request that they remove this status code.

Also mandatory disclaimer: while your case is not clear, it is NEVER recommended to wait for a domain to expire. If it is yours, renew it (even if you want to change registrars). If it is not, be aware that they are programs at various registrars that will register it as soon as possible (for a fee and/or an auction), so you won't have any chance manually to get it before them (so if you want it, it might be wiser to try to buy it from its current owner).